# Button to archive things in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I’ve started learning Ruby on Rails recently. I did blogger tutorial. And now I want to add button to archive articles. But I am not sure what I need to code. Can someone give me guidelines how to add button and archive existing articles and to default state to be draft, actually to have two state of article archived and draft ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You’re asking for a lot of work. For the button, you need a route and an action. For the default state, you can set that in a migration.

Answer (score 3):

1. add an action in your `ArticlesController` you can name it `archive`
2. add a route in your `config/routes.rb` with `patch` request
3. add a link on view with `remote: true`, this link will call the `archive` action
4. add code in `archive` action to update the article to set `archive` field to `true`
5. as you added `remote: true` in link, the action will look for the `archive.js.erb` file
6. create a file 'views/articles/archive.js.erb`
7. in `archive.js.erb` file, handle what should be done after archiving an article

Comment: Nice outline, which still makes them do most of the actual work.